# Custom accuracy in tff federated learning using keras.metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-federated

```
class BinaryTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='binary_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(BinaryTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    
        y_true = tf.squeeze(y_true)
   
        y_pred = tf.sign(y_pred)

        y_pred=tf.reshape(y_pred,[-1])
  
    
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.keras.backend.mean(tf.keras.backend.equal(y_true, 
        y_pred)))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        self.true_positives.assign(0)


    def model_fn():
        keras_model = create_keras_model()
        return tff.learning.from_keras_model(keras_model,
        input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,
        metrics=[BinaryTruePositives()])
```

```
TypeError: Expected tensorflow.python.keras.losses.Loss or collections.abc.Sequence, found function.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more of the stacktrace might be useful here, but I believe the issue in the code above is the fact  that `tf.keras.losses.MSE` is a *function* defining the loss logic, rather than an instance of `tf.keras.losses.Loss` itself.

Looking at an old version of TFF, it seems you are hitting [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.14.0/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py#L131), though note that you'd get a different error with a newer version of TFF (I believe you'd hit [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/keras_utils.py#L126) instead).

You can fix this by passing

```
loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
```

instead of the existing loss argument in your `model_fn` above.

Comment: Hi Keith Rush, Thank you for your response. The custom accuracy with tff worked for binary class only, but when I tried for multi-class, it throws a shape error, I tried to reshape y_true but did not work. The same custom accuracy works without federated learning. Can you please look into this? Thank you once again.